# Display the selected item so it appears in listbox? (Vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

VB.net

Hello, I was wondering if i could be able to do this:

I have a listbox "Listbox2", and I would like it to display what is selected to line 1 of "listbox1". I have tried a few methods but didnt seem to work. Any way to do so?

Comment: what did you try? can you paste the code?

Comment: You didn't try `listbox1.Items.Add(listbox2.SelectedText)` ?? Best to read a book if you are beginning programming, you can only google so far before you actually need to understand what you are doing. Good luck!

Comment: It's really not clear from your question exactly what you're trying to do. I don't know what you mean by "display what is selected to line 1 of 'listbox1'". Can you try rephrasing the question, and maybe showing us a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you're trying to achieve is to display the selected item from Listbox1 as an item in listbox2.

As your "question" leaved alot to my imagination, I took the liberty to provide a couple of different snippets.

## Provide the selected item's text:

First:
When an item is selected in Listbox1, an item is added at the top of Listbox2.

```
 Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        ListBox2.Items.Insert(0, ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    End Sub
```

Second:
When an item is selected in Listbox1, an item is added at the top of Listbox2 (Only one item will display)

```
 Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Listbox2.Items.Clear()
        ListBox2.Items.Insert(0, ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    End Sub
```

## Provide the first item's text:

(Doesn't neccessarily have to be on the SelectedIndexChanged event)
First:
When an item is selected in Listbox1, the top item adds to Listbox2.

```
 Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        ListBox2.Items.Insert(0, ListBox1.Items.Item(0))
    End Sub
```

Second:
When an item is selected in Listbox1, an item is added at the top of Listbox2 (Only one item will display)

```
 Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Listbox2.Items.Clear()
        ListBox2.Items.Insert(0, ListBox1.Items.Item(0))
    End Sub
```